# Расширить лимит строк и столбцов mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Сколько максимум строк и столбцов помещается в mysql? и как этот лимит расширить? [image: лимит]

Comment: Столько, на сколько хватит памяти, странный вопрос.

Comment: просто читал что пишут около 4000 ограничение

Comment: на qara пишут 4096

Comment: @ДанилВасильев это просто калька со стаковерфлоу

Comment: *просто читал что пишут* Документацию надо читать, а не ОБС. [Limits on Table Column Count and Row Size](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-count-limit.html). Это hard limit, а потому изменить его невозможно. Однако никто не запрещал вертикальный шардинг, который позволяет не сильно обращать внимание на это ограничение... к тому же структура с 4к полей однозначно намекает на определённые ошибки на стадии проектирования.

Comment: значит более 4к столбцов не запишется?

Comment: @ДанилВасильев таблица в 4к столбцов это все равно что для перевозки миллиона ящиков с грузами нанимать не 1000 грузовиков, а приделывать 10-ти километровый прицеп к одному тягачу